# How to execute bash script that requires multiply answers?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is the case. I have bash script that requires a couple of command to be executed. First of all, it requires `sudo`, then answer (`y/n`) and then password one more time. What I want to do is I want to execute it in one command.

Let's say I have my bash script - `myscript.sh`. This script requires `sudo` to be executed. So, to execute it in one line I can write:

```
echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S bash myscript.sh
```

And this will work. But after script is executed I need to answer `y` and type password one more time. How can I do that?

Here is what I have tried:

```
printf '%s\n mypassword y mypassword' | sudo -S bash myscript.sh
```

```
echo 'y\nmypassword\n' | echo 'mypassword' | sudo -S bash myscript.sh
```

And there were a couple more of what I have tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: so how many lines are printed with `printf '%s\n mypassword y mypassword'`

Comment: Why don't you pass the password as a command line argument to your script, and perform the relevant actions there with sudo and the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
printf '%s\n' mypassword y mypassword | ...
( echo mypassword; echo y; echo mypassword ) | ...
```

> This script requires sudo to

Note that typing that on the command line or in a script will publish your password. Instead, configure sudoers to allow the user to login without a password. Consider configuring credential caching in sudoers, so you don't have to type password twice.